# Is UAC an overestimated protection measure in Windows? Does Linux do it better?

Tags: malware, windows, linux, exploit, uac

Windows is an API-based operating system, whereas Linux is file-based. Hence in my opinion, any operating system API security measures alone aren't effective in Windows. One of such examples would be UAC in my humble opinion.
On the other hand, Linux incorporates SELinux and sudo instead. This goes to low-level layers of the operating system, which are harder to manipulate in my humble opinion. The Windows low-level approach (on older Windows Server systems at least) of pressing Alt+Ctrl+Del to login was a good approach in my opinion, but doesn't protect at all in this scenario in my opinion.

In my opinion, UAC only protects against a malfunctioning (digitally OR physically) mouse, which double clicks instead of single clicking and primitive forking malware/fork bombs.

- Is this the reason Linux has no real UAC equivalent, but rather other and  **actually** effective solutions?
- Does any compliance measure ever recommend to turn off UAC due to it being nearly useless?
- Is it technically smart to disable UAC completely if your threat model is not protecting against a malfunctioning mouse which clicks twice with a single click or primitive malware which forks itself and does not bypass UAC?
- Does the first to third paragraph contain any misconceptions/false information?
- Does UAC protect against BadUSB-based keystroke injection? No, because you can just click yes and no password is required, right? Or is there some randomization in play here, which a Ducky Script would fail at?
- Are UAC bypasses common on recent Windows systems? Supposedly there's a backdoor on default settings and at least(!) 77 ways to do it: https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME
- Does Linux solve these problems better?
- According to https://security.stackexchange.com/a/81770 the X window system is vulnerable to keyloggers, whereas Windows with UAC isn't, is this true? If so, does Wayland do better?

Comment: "In my opinion, UAC only protects against a malfunctioning (digitally OR physically) mouse"... really not sure why you think that.  It protects against running unauthorized executables or operations.  It's the same as Linux' "sudo" command, though much more secure.

Comment: @pcalkins because for example it would make me double click and execute an executable instead of dragging it into the trash bin or something like that...

Comment: "because you can just click yes and no password is required, right?"  If you haven't correctly configured it, sure.  So configure it to require password entry.

Comment: `In my opinion, UAC only protects against a malfunctioning (digitally OR physically) mouse, ` This is very much only an opinion. And I suspect only your personal one.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's the issue at hand - by default it does not require password entry...

Comment: @le3th4x0rbot that might be correct

Comment: @SirMuffington: The default UAC settings require password entry when launching with another account (equivalent to `sudo`), and only confirmation for elevating the same account.  And you can configure it to require password for elevation.  Both Linux+sudo and UAC protect you if you login as an ordinary user, and the default configuration of Linux gives you no protection when running as admin, while UAC gives some weak protection, and both can be configured to increase protection.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok, what about the AutoElevate Backdoor which is included with every recent Windows version which works with the default settings then?

Comment: @SirMuffington: Why are you allowing setup of two accounts (one limited, one root) on Linux, and not allowing the Windows PC to also have two accounts (one limited, one admin)?  If you want to talk about out-of-the-box "default settings" I could point you to an endless number of Linux configurations with a default password, which are far less secure than Windows.  So you have to include some small amount of on-site setup.

Comment: TLDR: Comparing Linux after configuration by an expert to Windows "out of the box" with no configuration allowed is not a fair or useful exercise.

Comment: @SirMuffington or it might be misguided and totally obtuse to the threat model which sudo/uac tries to mitigate.

Comment: In my humble opinion, in the most of the cases Linux IS secure by default. That's why most Linux installers install the user as a limited user and adds it to the sudoers file.